# Access data member of a unit from another unit Specman

Tags: specman

Say I have a unit, and I want to access a data member from another unit, for example this data member can be "Credits" in this following unit

```
unit SomeUnitToAccess like GeneralUnit {
   Credits : uint;
   keep Credits == 64;
};
```

```
unit SomeUnit like GeneralUnit {
    Var1 : uint;
    keep Var1 == <Var from another Unit>;
};
```

I want Var1 to be equal to Credits for example. I couldn't find an example for that in the docs.

Help would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Not sure what you're asking about. When you use the `unit` statement, you declare a unit *type*. There can be many instances of the same unit type, and these data members are instance members, not type members. So, where are these two units in the unit hierarchy, and which exactly instance's member you want to access? Or you mean that these are *static* data members (but then you would need to declare them as `static`) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one way would be using 'static field'. with static field you don't need to know where an instance of this type exists.

```
unit SomeUnitToAccess like GeneralUnit {


static Credits : uint = 64;
};

unit SomeUnit like GeneralUnit {
    Var1 : uint;
    keep Var1 == value( SomeUnitToAccess::Credits);
};
```

but static fields cannot be randomized, only assigned procedurally (like done here, in the field definition. or - in procedural code. for example - in pre_generate).

if you can't use static field, if you must randomize the Credits field, you can have a point in the SomeUnit, to an instance of SomeunitToAccess. then, should constrain this pointer. if this is difficult, if you cannot know where SomeunitToAccess is instantiated, there are ways to find it.
but assuming you know, then the code would be

```
unit SomeUnit like GeneralUnit {
    SomeUnitToAccess_p : SomeUnitToAccess;
    Var1 : uint;
    keep Var1 == SomeUnitToAccess_p.Credits; 
};

extend sys {
    SomeUnitToAccess is instance;
    SomeUnit is instance;

    keep SomeUnit.SomeUnitToAccess == SomeUnitToAccess;
};
```